# How do I add code to my Mail_Workbook vba to open everyday, refresh, send, then close?

Tags: excel, outlook-2007, vba

I need to add vba to open this workbook, refresh the data, automatically, send, then close.

Here is my code which works fine on it's own but I need to automate this daily.

```
Sub Mail_Workbook()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailAddr As String
Dim Subj As String



Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
.To = "me.meeee@company.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "***TEST*** " & Subj
.Body = Subj
.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
.Display
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Application.SendKeys "%S"
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like below. On workbook open it calls a procedure `RunMacro`.

The `RunMacro` procedure reads the values from the ranges and sets the time when the `MIS`
procedure has to be called.

`MIS` procedure will open the workbook, Refresh it , get a path to save the file and finally send the mail.

In the mail it will send the link for the workbook and wont attach the workbook. So you can save the workbook on any shared drive.

Put this code on `ThisWorkbook` code section

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    RunMacro
End Sub
```

Put this code in any Standard Module.

```
Sub RunMacro()


    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String, d As String, e As String

    a = Format(Range("A3"), "hh:mm:ss")
    b = Format(Range("A4"), "hh:mm:ss")
    c = Format(Range("A5"), "hh:mm:ss")
    d = Format(Range("A6"), "hh:mm:ss")
    e = Format(Range("A7"), "hh:mm:ss")


    Application.OnTime TimeValue(a), "MIS"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(b), "MIS"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(c), "MIS"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(d), "MIS"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(e), "MIS"
End Sub

Sub MIS()

'open the workbook
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim Path As String, strFile As String, strFilePath As String

    strFile = "file1.xlsx"
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

    If IsWorkBookOpen(Path) Then
        Set wkb = Workbooks(strFile)
    Else
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Path)
    End If

    'Refresh the data
    wkb.RefreshAll

    'get new filePath
    strFilePath = getFileLink

    wkb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath 
    wkb.Close

    'send mail
    SendMail strFilePath


End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
'Check if workbooks is open
'IsOpen Return true

    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0: IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70: IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function

Sub SendMail(myDest As String)
'procedure to send mail
'you need to configure the server & port

    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim Flds As Variant


    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields

    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "test-svr-002"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With

    With iMsg

        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = "test@gmail.com"
        .From = "test@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "MIS Reports" & " " & Date & " " & Time
        .TextBody = "Link to Mis Report :" & vbNewLine & "<" & myDest & ">"
        .Send
    End With

    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing

End Sub

Function getFileLink() As String

    Dim fso As Object, MyFolder As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    MyFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports"


    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If

    MyFolder = MyFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "MMM_YYYY")

    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If

    getFileLink = MyFolder & "\MIS " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY hh.mm.ss") & ".xls"
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: This works great!  thanks so much.  How would I make it open, refresh everyday at 4:30PM?

Comment: @user184581 Enter the time in cell A3,A4.....so on and you can extend that. For running this macro the PC has to be standalone. I I am using the same macro in my office which is running sucessfully. What user does is in the morning he opens up this workbook and it runs on time which is specified in the range. I will suggest you this approach.

Comment: I found another way to do it and it works great except I can't use MS Task Scheduler in my remote environment.  Which is where I have to open the excel file with the access query embedded.  I like the code above but I don't want to send the data via link.....I'd prefer html to email body in the below method.  But how can I automate this without scheduler?

Comment: This Workbook

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Run "Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body"
    End Sub

Comment: Module1

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
 
    ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
End Function                   Left the rest of the code out because it was too long

Comment: Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()
' You need to use this module with the RangetoHTML subroutine.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
 
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ' You can also use a sheet name here.
    Set rng = Sheets("Low Margin with SaleId").UsedRange
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")